# click on navbar and scroll to item id not working through script

Tags: jquery, scroll, smoothing

I wanted to create a  smooth scroll effect on my website similar to this:
http://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2/

My website has a fixed top navbar with 3 body sections: one with a slideshow gallery, one with bootstrap tabs and one with a map.

At the very end of the body tag I have:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/Gym_website.js" type="text/javascript"></script> // js file for the slideshow of the gallery
<script src="js/Gym_scroll_jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> // js file with smooth scroll effect
```

I used the href and id tags in the html code( like in the tutorial) and I noticed that when I click the navbar items the webpage jumps to the anchor with out any scroll effect and does not consider the js file.

Even if i don't use the js file the page still jumps to the specific anchor when I click the navbar items.

I don't know if this is done through html or bootsrap???
I want to make the scroll effect to work, not to have a jump to the anchor, but I don't know how.

Another problem is that when I jump to the section with the tabs it goes lower than it should.
I would like to set an offset only for this element.

I searched for hours on the internet and forums, but I could not find an answer and I would much appreciate some your help.

Thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!--end meta tags -->
    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Gym_website.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css">
  <!--end css and bootstrap links -->

  <title> Eli's Gym</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>   
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>                      
       </button>
    
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     <img class="logo" src="img/Eli_s-gym1.png" alt="Eli_s-gym">
    </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li class="active gallery"><a href="#">Galerie</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tarife" id="nav_tarife">Tarife</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#contact" id="nav_contact">Contact</a></li> 
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav> <!--Ending of navbar-->
  
  <div class="slideshow-container container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
     <img class="mySlides img-responsive" src="img/01.jpg" alt="gym_01">
     <img class="mySlides img-responsive" src="img/02.jpg" alt="gym_02">
     <img class="mySlides img-responsive" src="img/03.jpg" alt="gym_03">
     <img class="mySlides img-responsive" src="img/04.jpg" alt="gym_04">
     <img class="mySlides img-responsive" src="img/05.jpg" alt="gym_05">
     <img class="mySlides img-responsive" src="img/06.jpg" alt="gym_06">
     <img class="mySlides img-responsive" src="img/07.jpg" alt="gym_07">
     <img class="mySlides img-responsive" src="img/08.jpg" alt="gym_08">
    </div>
   
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <img class="gym_thumbnails_slides img-responsive" src="img/01.jpg" alt="gym_thumbnails_01" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
      <img class="gym_thumbnails_slides img-responsive" src="img/02.jpg" alt="gym_thumbnails_02" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
      <img class="gym_thumbnails_slides img-responsive" src="img/03.jpg" alt="gym_thumbnails_03" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
      <img class="gym_thumbnails_slides img-responsive" src="img/04.jpg" alt="gym_thumbnails_04" onclick="currentSlide(4)">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <img class="gym_thumbnails_slides last_column img-responsive" src="img/05.jpg" alt="gym_thumbnails_05" onclick="currentSlide(5)">
      <img class="gym_thumbnails_slides last_column img-responsive" src="img/06.jpg" alt="gym_thumbnails_06" onclick="currentSlide(6)">
      <img class="gym_thumbnails_slides last_column img-responsive" src="img/07.jpg" alt="gym_thumbnails_07" onclick="currentSlide(7)">
      <img class="gym_thumbnails_slides last_column img-responsive" src="img/08.jpg" alt="gym_thumbnails_08" onclick="currentSlide(8)">
    </div>
   </div> <!--end row-->
  </div> <!--end slideshow-container container -->
  
  <div class="container-fluid subscription category_name">
   <p href="#nav_tarife" id="tarife">Tarife</p>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
     <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Fitness & Bodybuilding</a></li>
     <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Aerobic & Zumba</a></li>
     <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Antrenor personal</a></li>

    </ul>
    
    <div class="tab-content">
     <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <table>
       <tr>
        <th>PERIOADA</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">PRET</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>1 sedinta</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">25 RON</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>8 sedinte in decurs de 30 zile</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">100 RON</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>12 sedinte in decurs de 30 zile</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">125 RON</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>Abonament nelimitat 1 luna</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">150 RON</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>Abonament 1 luna Happy Hour</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">120 RON</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>Abonament 1 luna student/ elev</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">120 RON</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>Abonament 1 luna student/ elev/ Happy Hour</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">90 RON</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>Abonament 1 luna Family</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">270 RON</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>Abonament 1 luna Family/ Happy Hour</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">210 RON</th>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
     
     <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <table>
       <tr>
        <th>PERIOADA</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">PRET</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>Fitness 4 sedinte & Zumba 8 sedinte</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">140 RON</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>Fitness 8 sedinte & Zumba 4 sedinte
        <th class="side_tab_text">150 RON</th>
       </tr>
        <th>Fitness 4 sedinte & Zumba 12 sedinte</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">160 RON</th>
       </tr> 
        <th>Fitness 8 sedinte & Zumba 8 sedinte</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">180 RON</th>
       </tr> 
        <th>Fitness nelimitat & Zumba 4 sedinte</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">180 RON</th>
       </tr> 
        <th>Fittness nelimitat & Zumba 8 sedinte</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">210 RON</th>
       </tr> 
        <th>Fitness nelimitat & Zumba 12 sedinte</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">240 RON</th>
       </tr> 
      </table>
     </div>
     
     <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <table>
       <tr>
        <th>PERIOADA</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">PRET</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>1 sedinta</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">20 RON</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>8 sedinte in decurs de 30 zile</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">80 RON</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>12 sedinte in decurs de 30 zile</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">120 RON</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>1 luna</th>
        <th class="side_tab_text">160 RON</th>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!--Ending of gym_rates-->
  
  <div class="container-fluid contact category_name">
   <div class="bottom_container">
   <p href="#nav_contact" id="contact">Contact</p>
   <h2>Va asteptam la sediu:</h2>
   <div id="contact_map">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1148.8130081116574!2d23.608778597460674!3d46.77764414131094!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47490c190888e1f3%3A0x45d919b03906539a!2sBulevardul+21+Decembrie+1989+129%2C+Cluj-Napoca+400000!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sro!4v1459274575556" width="100%" height="350px" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
   <br>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span><h2> Telefon:</h2>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span><h2> Scrieti-ne pe email:</h2>
     </div>
    </div>
    &nbsp;
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
       <h2 class="details">0747301276</h2>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-sm-6">
       <h2 class="details">elis_gym@gmail.com</h2>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> <!--Ending of contact-->
  
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script> 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/Gym_website.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/Gym_scroll_jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure exactly how that smooth scrolling script works, it may need something to trigger it. Alternatively, take a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: Thank you. The code helped me very much.